# GWT 2.1 Data Presentation Widgets without paging

Tags: gwt, tabular

I am trying to build a table with large dataset and would like to avoid paging.  (I would like to do something similar to Yahoo Mail grid which retrieves data after the grid is drawn.  I think initially the first 100 mails are retrieved and then mail is only retrieved after the user scrolls down)

The example of the data presentation widget I have seen include paging.  Is it possible to do what I want?

**edit:** You could also call this an infinite scroll table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dean already mentioned Ext GWT but I'd like to suggest [SmartGWT's implementation](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_live) as well.

Comment: Your link wasn't correct but I found it anyways.  I like it: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_live

Answer (score 4):

There are an exemple of this in the [GWT Showcase](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#A1edwVHBClQ/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/cell/ShowMorePagerPanel.java&q=CwCellList%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com&d=11)

```
/**
 * A scrolling pager that automatically increases the range every time the
 * scroll bar reaches the bottom.
 */
public class ShowMorePagerPanel extends AbstractPager {

  /**
   * The default increment size.
   */
  private static final int DEFAULT_INCREMENT = 20;

  /**
   * The increment size.
   */
  private int incrementSize = DEFAULT_INCREMENT;

  /**
   * The last scroll position.
   */
  private int lastScrollPos = 0;

  /**
   * The scrollable panel.
   */
  private final ScrollPanel scrollable = new ScrollPanel();

  /**
   * Construct a new {@link ShowMorePagerPanel}.
   */
  public ShowMorePagerPanel() {
    initWidget(scrollable);

    // Handle scroll events.
    scrollable.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
      public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        // If scrolling up, ignore the event.
        int oldScrollPos = lastScrollPos;
        lastScrollPos = scrollable.getScrollPosition();
        if (oldScrollPos >= lastScrollPos) {
          return;
        }

        HasRows display = getDisplay();
        if (display == null) {
          return;
        }
        int maxScrollTop = scrollable.getWidget().getOffsetHeight()
            - scrollable.getOffsetHeight();
        if (lastScrollPos >= maxScrollTop) {
          // We are near the end, so increase the page size.
          int newPageSize = Math.min(
              display.getVisibleRange().getLength() + incrementSize,
              display.getRowCount());
          display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get the number of rows by which the range is increased when the scrollbar
   * reaches the bottom.
   *
   * @return the increment size
   */
  public int getIncrementSize() {
    return incrementSize;
  }

  @Override
  public void setDisplay(HasRows display) {
    assert display instanceof Widget : "display must extend Widget";
    scrollable.setWidget((Widget) display);
    super.setDisplay(display);
  }

  /**
   * Set the number of rows by which the range is increased when the scrollbar
   * reaches the bottom.
   *
   * @param incrementSize the incremental number of rows
   */
  public void setIncrementSize(int incrementSize) {
    this.incrementSize = incrementSize;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRangeOrRowCountChanged() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There used to be an example of that called DynaGrid [here](http://www.zwitserloot.com/tipit-gwtlib/example) but that link is dead now. I haven't been able to find it anywhere else (note: that's not the same as the [DynaGrid on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dynagrid/)). You might be able to contact the author, Reinier Zwitserloot, to inquire about getting a copy of his DynaGrid. You could also search the [GWT Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit) and if you don't find anything, post there asking if anyone else knows where to find it.

Comment: I tried looking for a dynagrid but haven't been able to find it.  Also, I would like to use a widget that is being used by others and is maintained.  That is why I wanted to use the data presentation widget.

Answer (score 0):

Ext Gwt (AKA GXT) has an implementation of a "Live Grid" that supports this functionality (see http://www.sencha.com/examples/explorer.html#livegrid). The code is GPL although you can buy a license to use this in commercial applications.