# CellTree "Show More" programmatically

Tags: gwt, pager

does anyone know how to trigger the "Show More" functionality of a GWT CellTree programmatically, without having to click on the Show More button?

My aim is to implement a kind of pager that increments the number of elements displayed when the user scrolls down a ScollPanel, so it would be something like:

```
//inside pager class

onScroll(ScrollEvent)
{

    //here I would call CellTree's show more

}
```

I've been looking the CellTree and CellTreeNodeView classes code but I couldn't find a clear way to do it.

I know the class CellTreeNodeView has a showMore function which is the one who performs this action, but I don't know how to get it called from another class. I'd need a CellTreeNodeView object, and dont' know how to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129104/gwt-2-1-data-presentation-widgets-without-paging/4018096#4018096

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a package protected method in a package protected class CellTreeNodeView i.e only code in com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client can invoke it.

```
  void showMore()
```

### Extremely hacky solution

1) The only way around it is . Copy CellTreeNodeView and CellTree into your code base (maintain the package )

2) Change the **accessors** to public to allow you to invoke showMore as per your requirement.

3) Ensure you test for all possible flows.

4) Ensure the copied classes in your code base appear in a higher classpath hieararchy to GWT Compiler than gwt-user jar thus ensuring your modified classes get picked up rather than original ones.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working exactly as I wanted, and without having to copy the code from the protected original GWT.

The point was firing the same event as the "Show more" button, so I created a fake onMouseDown event, and triggered it with the show more button as the target:

```
final ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel();

sp.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event)
  {
    int maxScrollBottom = sp.getWidget().getOffsetHeight()
        - sp.getOffsetHeight();

    if (sp.getVerticalScrollPosition() >= maxScrollBottom) {
      NativeEvent clickEvent = Document.get().createMouseDownEvent(0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0);
      Element target = (Element) cellTree.getCellTree().getElement().getLastChild().getFirstChild().getLastChild();
      target.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you a lot, anyway! :D

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is this one:

```
public static void makeShowMoreVisible(Element element, boolean isVisible) {
    ArrayList<Element> result = new ArrayList<Element>();
    findShowMore(result, element);  

    for (Element elt : result) {
        if (isVisible) {
            element.getStyle().clearDisplay();
        } else {  
            element.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE); 
        }
    }
}

private static void findShowMore(ArrayList res, Element element) {
    String c;

    if (element == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (element.getInnerText().equals("Show more")) {
        res.add(element);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DOM.getChildCount(element); i++) {
        Element child = DOM.getChild(element, i);
        findShowMore(res, child);   
    }
}
```